# LLDB: How to inspect unordered_map

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, lldb

Most other STL containers print fine, but `unordered_map` is a mess.

I use `operator <<` for prints, but this isn't about printing, this is about when I am crashed and I want to print out my hash from the LLDB prompt.

I cannot call something like `call cout << var` because that does not work.

Is there no solution other than e.g. linking a template function that itself uses `cout <<`? Would that even work? (I am trying, but it does not work because I have to know ahead of time what the template parameter types will be for it to generate and link the code for them)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to examine the `unordered_map` object itself, without calling methods on it.

For example, take this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, string> map;
    map[0] = "mary";
    map[1] = "had";
    map[2] = "a";
    map[3] = "little";
    map[4] = "lamb";

    return 0;
}

$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g unmap.cpp -o unmap
$ lldb unmap
Current executable set to 'unmap' (x86_64).
(lldb) break set --name main
```

*`lldb` output not shown for brevity*

```
(lldb) proc launch
```

*`n` entered 5 times until `return 0;` statement*

```
(lldb)
Process 18063 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0000000100000aea unmap`main + 1082 at unmap.cpp:15, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000aea unmap`main + 1082 at unmap.cpp:15
   12       map[3] = "little";
   13       map[4] = "lamb";
   14
-> 15       return 0;
   16   }
   17
```

And then examine the object using `p`:

```
(lldb) p map[0]
(std::__1::unordered_map<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::hash<int>, std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::mapped_type) $2 = "mary"
(lldb) p map[1]
(std::__1::unordered_map<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::hash<int>, std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::mapped_type) $3 = "had"
(lldb) quit
```

The version of `lldb` you use will make a difference, as it's improving all the time:

```
$ lldb -version
LLDB-179.5
```

(i.e. the one that comes with the Xcode 5 DP 6 command line package)

Comment: how to attach to ARM process from lldb from cmdline? Can I attach two instances to the same running program? (something tells me no...) What about upgrading the version of lldb in Xcode without upgrading Xcode? (I wanna keep Xcode 4 because of vim plugin) I do have the lldb project itself successfully compiling via Xcode.

Comment: @StevenLu No, I don't know how you'd do that, but you can interact with LLDB from within Xcode using the debugger console.  I would try with the version of LLDB you have to see if you can do things like `p map[0]`.

Comment: I have LLDB `179.6`. It fails: `p this->memberUnorderedMap[0] error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function` `p memberUnorderedMap[0] error: use of undeclared identifier 'memberUnorderedMap'` (I can get a super ugly dump of the whole map itself using `p this->memberUnorderedMap`)

Comment: @StevenLu Why are you using `this->`?

Comment: It's the only way to get it to print anything at all in the instance of the object

Comment: @StevenLu Oh OK.  I'd need to see some code to see how this could be done.

Comment: just have the map be a member of a class. Then break program in middle of member function of that class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go with the open source lldb and hand-build it yourself, there is a synthetic provider for unordered_map that you could use:

> Author: enrico Date: Wed Sep  4 12:48:52 2013 New Revision: 189964
>
> URL: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?rev=189964&view=rev Log: This
>   is an example synthetic provider for libc++ unordered (multi) maps&set
>   Thanks to Jared Grubb for writing it and sharing it!

Comment: it's not clear how to integrate this with Xcode so I can attach and debug an ARM application without some complex setup process each time

Comment: Yeah, debugging on the phone is probably the tricky issue in all of this approach.
What you could try, with no promise of it working, is just extracting the Python script from the ToT sources, and “command script import”ing it into your Xcode session. That might or might not work depending on the version of Xcode/LLDB you are using, and how much the SB API has evolved since then (in terms of calls available/bugs fixed). Usually, these scripts are not written with much thought about being compatible with older LLDBs, and no such testing is done. It might work. If it does, it’s your lucky day :)

Comment: Yeah. my template-pretty-printers are so effective, though, that logging of sufficient granularity pretty much gets any conceivable job done at this point. I would probably be better served to work on a network-based logger system rather than trying to tweak the debugger.